# Lighting on Chanuka for advertising the mitzva?

Tags: rashi, talmud-bavli, menora-chanukia, maseches-shabbos, miracle

The *Bavli*, [Shabbos 21b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=21b&format=pdf), discusses lighting the *Chanuka* lights out of doors; *Rashi* gives the reason for outdoor lighting as

> משום פרסומי ניסא / for advertising the miracle.

Further down the *amud*, the *Bavli* discusses a storekeeper who lights the *Chanuka* lighs outside his store. He can do so, and is not liable if flammable materials come into contact with his lamp, *Rashi* explains,

> שברשות פירסום מצוה הניחה שם / because he had placed it there on the authority of advertising a command (*mitzva*).

A *command*? Isn't placing the lights outside advertising the *miracle*? What does *Rashi* mean here by "advertising a command", and why does he say it?

Comment: He is publicizing to others that they should light their own Chanuka candles (it is his store, not his house).

Comment: @Yishai, my _chavrusa_ thought that may be it. Do you have a source, though, that says so?

Comment: Cf. *P'nei Y'hoshua* ([*M'gilla* 4a](http://books.google.com/books?id=vEovAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT436&lpg=PT436#v=onepage&q&f=false), ¶ discussing Tos. ibid. s.v. מאי איריא), who uses the term (vis-a-vis Purim) to refer to publicizing that *Chazal* instituted the holiday and its associated *mitzva*. He seems to carry this explanation into his discussion of the following Tosafos, contrasting the daytime reading (which essentially fulfills *pirsumei nisa* since the miracle happened during the day) with the nighttime reading (which merely publicizes that *Chazal* made the day special via *mitzvos*).

Comment: @msh210, that a store doesn't fulfill the Mitzvah? I could look if you need. That this is what Rashi is talking about? No. If I had that, I would have made it an answer.

Comment: @Yishai, yeah, I meant the latter. Oh, well.